# which is the better way to install Confluent schema registry, kafka and zookeeper in production

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Which is the better way to install kafka, zookeeper and schema registry? I already have installed kafka and zookeeper from their official site, but I noticed that on the confluent schema registry package it comes with kafka and zookeeper too, so will I need download the package and only use schema registry? or there is another link where I can download schema registry without the kafka and zookeper part?, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to install it all from the same place. Confluent offers the Confluent Platform community edition that includes:

- Zookeeper
- Kafka
- Schema Registry
- Kafka Connect
- REST Proxy
- KSQL Server

That way you will avoid any version incompatibilities. I followed the instructions from [Confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/zip-tar.html) to get the entire suite installed and running.

Together with the [command line tool](https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html#confluent-cli) you will be able to start and stop all necessary services with only one command:

```
confluent local start
```

They also offer Docker installation which might be of interest to you as well.

Comment: But if I wanto to install zookeeper in one server i just copy the entire package and use zookeeper in that server and later I copy again that package to another server and I use kafka for example? this package is for production ?

Comment: the links given in my answer are not for a production installation. Maybe I misunderstood your question then because I do not think that your production installation should be based on an answer on Stackoverflow :) Please add more details to your question what you try to achieve in the end.

Comment: if you want to use your own Zookeeper installation, you can always overwrite the properties files.

Comment: sorry if I'm not explain myself correctly, I want to know how to install schema registry in a production environment, I read that I can use kafka and zookeeper from their official site for a production environment but for schema registry I don't know how